# how the workflow runtime obtains all of the information about the activity in wf 4.0 so that we can alter the execution sequence?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

How the workflow runtime knows about its activity order and parameter. Can we alter the execution behaviour or order of activity execution in runing workflow?

My requirment is how to control the activity execution so that we can explicitly get current execution activity , stop, re run and change parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can alter the execution order by creating custom control flow activity. This can be done by inheriting NativeActivity.
For example, creating custom sequence activity you can go through this example.
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/VBWF4CustomSequenceActivity-cd65cb4c